# During compilation in Visual Studio (C) i cant get a correct debug

Tags: c, visual-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a;
    a = 4;
    printf("a = %d \n");
    return 0;
}
```

and that is what i get when debug:

a = 1220497792 or other big numbers.

Comment: `printf("a = %d \n");` -> `printf("a = %d \n", a);`. Did you read the compiler warnings?

Comment: @Jabberwocky got it.  `printf` is a variadic function meaning it can accept a variable number of arguments.  `printf` doesn't know how many addional arguments are required until it counts all the format specifiers (`%d` here).  Also, make sure warnings are turned on.  Your compiler should have been whining about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing anything to you're `printf` call so it is printing garbage.

To fix you need to pass `a` as a second argument to `printf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a;
    a = 4;
    printf("a = %d \n", a);
    return 0;
}
```